# Unhide all hidden files, folders, subfolders and subfiles except access denied path using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file-io

My code below albe to Unhide all hidden files, folders, subfolders and subfiles. The problem is it'll stop if any access denied path. How to make the code skip access denied path and continue with other paths.

```
Dim MyDrive As String = "D:\"
Dim FileCounter As Integer = 0
Dim FolderCounter As Integer = 0
Dim DriveObj As New IO.DirectoryInfo(MyDrive)

Dim Files As IO.FileInfo() = DriveObj.GetFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim Directories As IO.DirectoryInfo() = DriveObj.GetDirectories("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    Dim Filename As IO.FileSystemInfo
        For Each Filename In Files
            On Error Resume Next
            If (IO.File.GetAttributes(Filename.FullName) And IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) = IO.FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                ' Show the file.
                IO.File.SetAttributes(Filename.FullName, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
                FileCounter = FileCounter + 1
            End If
        Next

        Dim DirectoryName As IO.DirectoryInfo
        For Each DirectoryName In Directories
            On Error Resume Next
            If (IO.File.GetAttributes(DirectoryName.FullName) And IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) = IO.FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                ' Show the folder.
                IO.File.SetAttributes(DirectoryName.FullName, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
                FolderCounter = FolderCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: look into Try/Catch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was testing code, I realised that `DriveObj.GetFiles(...)` and `DriveObj.GetDirectories(...)` are stopping when access is denied, not `For` loops. To fix that, you have to use recursive file and directory listing.

```
Private Function GetFilesRecursive(ByVal initial As String) As List(Of String)
    ' This list stores the results.
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    ' This stack stores the directories to process.
    Dim stack As New Stack(Of String)

    ' Add the initial directory
    stack.Push(initial)

    ' Continue processing for each stacked directory
    Do While (stack.Count > 0)
        ' Get top directory string
        Dim dir As String = stack.Pop
        Try
            ' Add all immediate file paths
            result.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*"))

            ' Loop through all subdirectories and add them to the stack.
            Dim directoryName As String
            For Each directoryName In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
                stack.Push(directoryName)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Loop

    ' Return the list
    Return result
End Function

Private Function GetDirectoriesRecursive(ByVal initial As String) As List(Of String)
    ' This list stores the results.
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    ' This stack stores the directories to process.
    Dim stack As New Stack(Of String)

    ' Add the initial directory
    stack.Push(initial)

    ' Continue processing for each stacked directory
    Do While (stack.Count > 0)
        ' Get top directory string
        Dim dir As String = stack.Pop
        Try
            ' Add all immediate file paths
            result.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*.*"))

            ' Loop through all subdirectories and add them to the stack.
            Dim directoryName As String
            For Each directoryName In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
                stack.Push(directoryName)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Loop

    ' Return the list
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Unhide()
    Dim MyDrive As String = "D:\"
    Dim FileCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim FolderCounter As Integer = 0

    Dim Files As List(Of String) = GetFilesRecursive(MyDrive)
    Dim Directories As List(Of String) = GetDirectoriesRecursive(MyDrive)

    For Each Filename In Files
        If (IO.File.GetAttributes(Filename) And IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) = IO.FileAttributes.Hidden Then
            'Show the file.
            IO.File.SetAttributes(Filename, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
            FileCounter = FileCounter + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each DirectoryName In Directories
        If (IO.File.GetAttributes(DirectoryName) And IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) = IO.FileAttributes.Hidden Then
            'Show the folder.
            IO.File.SetAttributes(DirectoryName, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
            FolderCounter = FolderCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the solution, however it would be a better idea to mention what type of exception for the sake of readability and ensure there are no other issues.